# Power BI: The lowest value between two columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

is there a possibility to find the lowest value between two columns in Power BI?

This is the table:

| Name | Maths | Physics |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Emma | 73.2 | 32.5 |
| Theo | 95.3 | 76.5 |
| Ellen | 52.7 | 99.7 |

I have to get a card that would in this case show Emma because if we compare both exams, the worst result got Emma from Physics.

Preferably, the card would say Emma 32.5, but Emma is fine, too.

**My research:**

these two ways give a good result, but only for one column:

First:

```
MinResult = CALCULATE(MIN(results(Name),TOPN(1,'results',results[Maths],ASC))
```

Second:

```
MinResult = 
    CALCULATE(
        MIN(results(Name),
        results[Maths] = MIN(results[Maths])
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You can add an expression to the `TOPN`.

```
MinResult =
  CALCULATE(
    MIN(results[Name]),
    TOPN(1, 'results', MIN([Maths], [Physics]), ASC)
  )
```

And with score:

```
MinResult = 
  CALCULATE(
    MIN(results[Name]) & " " & MIN( MIN(results[Maths]), MIN(results[Physics]) ),
    TOPN(1, 'results', MIN([Maths], [Physics]), ASC)
  )
```

You may want to consider whether Unpivoting your table in PowerQuery would be more useful:

[image]

Comment: Ohh, I have actually tried MIN(MIN([Maths]), MIN([Physics])) but it gave me the wrong result. So yea, close.

Comment: And thanks Sam, you definitely have the best answers that always work. I'm always happy when I see that you are the one who answered. :)

Comment: Ohh, about pivoting, I thought about that, but it seemed to me that it is a bit unprofessional, let's say a dirty fix, because everything in Name column is doubled. The real data that I work on is way more complicated so doubling would be an issue.

Comment: Not at all. Fact tables are built this way (usually with Name Id, and Subject Id with their respective dimension tables). Working with rows is way easier than working with columns. The VertiPaq Engine in Power BI does a great job on [Cardinality Of A Column](https://blog.enterprisedna.co/vertipaq-engine-in-power-bi-usage-best-practices/#Cardinality_Of_A_Column)

Comment: Hmm, I agree about working with rows being easier, but if you have for example 2000 name ids that are doubled (so that would be 4000) wouldn't that be an issue, especially if those name ids are used in 10 other tables as a key?

Comment: It really, really isn't. Check out [Understand star schema and the importance for Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema)